# window.Open in MVC view

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this view

How to pass the controller for `window.open` correctly?

the way it is is not working well.

There is another event that works well in IE to open a new window than the `window.open`?

```
@model IEnumerable<xxx>

@{

    var grid = new 
        .WebGrid(
                id: idGrid, rowsPerPage: this.RowsPerPage,
                ajaxUpdateContainerId: idGrid
                );
    var columns = new WebGridColumn[] {
        grid.Column(columnName:"Book", 
                    header: "My Text",
                    format: (item) => @Html.Raw(String.Format("<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='EditBook({0})'>{1}</a>", item.Id, item.Code))
                    ),
        [...]

    };

}

<script type='text/javascript'>
    function EditBook(id) {
        window.open('@Url.Action("Edit","Book")' + '?id=' + id);
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: Now that you've changed it, does it work?

Comment: Not worked.. in reality had been a mistake when writing the question

Comment: Use firebug debugger or similar and set a breakpoint in the function to see if it is being hit when you click on the link. Thatw ill narrow down where the error is.

Comment: Your code looks fine. Do you have any js error in your page ?

Comment: In IE does not worked. Firefox and Chrome yeah.

Comment: I've mocked it up in plain HTML and it works on IE and firefox for me. It must be something to do with the link that is generated. Can you post a snippet of the geneated HTML with the <a> element in it?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the onclick handler to:

```
onclick='function() {{ EditBook({0}); }}'
```